# If $X$ is a discrete random variable, and $Y,I$ are indicator random variables, how can we find $P(Y|X,I)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have that there are $N$ people with a unique label $\{1,\ldots, N\}$. Suppose that I sample uniformly from this and obtain a person. I call this $X$ and it can equal some person $\{1,\ldots, N\}$. Each sampled person is asked if they would like to respond to a question, the form of which is a "yes/no" question. They agree to respond with probability $r_i$, and don't agree to respond with probability $1-r_i$. Once they agree to respond, they will say "yes" (represented by $1$) with probability $p_i$ and say "no" (represented by $0$) with probability $1-p_i$.

We can parametrize these decisions with $X$, $Y$, and $I$.

$X \in \{1,\ldots, N\}$, sampled uniformly

$$
I = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if person}\ X \ \text{decides to respond, with probability} \ r_i \\
    0, & \text{if person}\ X \ \text{decides not to respond, with probability} \ 1-r_i \\
  \end{cases}
$$

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if person}\ X \ \text{decides to respond, and responds with "YES" with probability} \ p_i \\
    0, & \text{if person}\ X \ \text{decides to respond, and responds with "NO" with probability} \ 1-p_i \\
  \end{cases}
$$

I am trying to find the joint distribution $p(X,I,Y)$. So far what I have is:

$$
p(X,I,Y) = p(Y|X,I)\cdot p(X|I)\cdot p(X)
$$

I have that $p(X) = \frac{1}{N}$,

and $p(X|I) = r_X \mathbb{1}_{\{I=1\}} +(1-r_X)\mathbb{1}_{\{I=0\}}$.

However, I am not sure what $p(Y|X,I)$ should be. Specifically, since $X,I$ are discrete random variables, I understand that the conditional probability should be of the form $p(Y|X=x,I=i)$, but I am not sure what the final form should be. Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a problem, in that you only ever have a defined value of $Y$ when $I = 1$. So you have no real idea of what "The answer a person would give, in the event that the person will not give an answer" *is*.

And that very fact is why surveys have non-response bias. There are two things you can do:

1. Minimise $P(I = 0)$, so that you can put bounds on your overall estimates (i.e. control how much of an effect the non-response can have on your results).
2. Model $P(Y | I = 0)$ based on what you know about $P(Y | I = 1)$. You can assume that response propensity and actual response are independent (called "missing completely at random"), you can assume that they are independent once you condition on a common set of covariates (called "missing at random"), and in some cases you can assume some specific structure to their direct correlation, but in general you can never be entirely certain that you're right because you will never have direct information about that part of the population.

If you're interested in the topic more, then you probably want to track down the work of Robert Groves, who describes the various mechanisms for non-response and means of adjusting for them where possible.